# Постинг свежих новостей в телеграм-канал через бота

Tags: python, telebot, beautiful-soup

Есть бот, который парсит новостной сайт и отправляет каждую свежую новость в телеграм-канал. В теории, он должен каждые полчаса проверять, не появилось ли на сайте чего-то нового, если не появилось - засыпать обратно на полчаса. Но у меня он продолжает слать одну и ту же новость по несколько раз, если не было запощено ничего нового.

Проблема в том, что у новостей нет уникального id, поэтому я не знаю, как сравнить их между собой и не отправлять одну и ту же статью несколько раз.
Буду рада любым подсказкам.

```
import telebot
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import time

token = os.environ['TOKEN']
bot = telebot.TeleBot(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
channel_id = '@name'


url = 'https://vc.ru/new'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
post = soup.find('div', class_="feed__item l-island-round")
title = post.find("div", class_="content-container").text.strip()
post_url = post.find("a", class_="content-link", href=True)["href"].strip()


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(channel_id, 'Начинаем постинг новостей')
    while True:
        n = bot.send_message(channel_id, title + post_url)
        time.sleep(1800)
        if message.text == n.text:
            time.sleep(1800)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: так пишите в базу/файл заголовок или часть статьи или того, кто написал, или дату публикации или все вместе, неважно. и сравнивайте информацию. если была - не надо, не было - надо, и сделали новую запись в базу.

Comment: тоже озадачился парсингом новостей с VC, но у меня другая проблема, на моем компе если запустить все работает, при выгрузке на хостинг пилит ошибку предполагаю что нужно через прокси сделать это парсинг, не пробовали ли загружать на хостинг бота?